# Doesn't seem to be posting

Tags: authentication, python-3.2

I'm trying to write a login script for a site called Yakedi, its a free-sms service.
Tho as much as I have tried, and normally I don't ask people for help because I like to figure things out on my own, I am stuck.  I am writing in Python 3.2.2.  So please can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
import urllib
import sys
import http.cookiejar

cookieJar = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))

opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', "Mozilla/5.0")]

username = "insert email here"
password = "insert password here"

url = "http://yakedi.com/login/do"

form = { "email" : username,
         "pass" : password,
         "submit": "login"}

encodedForm = urllib.parse.urlencode(form).encode("UTF-8")
request = urllib.request.Request(url, encodedForm)
page = opener.open(request)
contents = page.read()

print(contents)
```

Thank you in return

Comment: What makes you think that it's not posting? I ran the script and monitored traffic with wireshark and it posted fine... what are you trying to do with contents?